# Angular replace component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ngonchanges

There is a case where the data are being sent from two different components; let's say `OneComponent` and `TwoComponent` and there is a `ResultComponent` which receive these data via `Input()` decorator. Also, in `ResultComponent` the data are merged using `OnChanges` interface:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['dataFromCompTwo']) {
      this.dataFromComp = this.dataFromCompTwo;
    }
  }
```

and data are shown in this component, but component is instantiated twice and the data are double. 
How to check if data are already sent from one of the components and show only last sent data?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwnaeg) => I would like to show *Here is result* just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inter-components communication. You should use one of the techniques described [on this Angular documentation page](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

I personnaly favor [communication through a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) because components are then not coupled at all: the communication method does not depend on their inclusion in the DOM so you can move them around as you please, it won't break.

Answer (score 1):

if you have two components sending changes then you can access these using:

- changes.componentOne
- changes.componentTwo

The `SimpleChanges` has another property called `firstChange` which you can use to check if this is the first change coming from that specific component like this:

- `changes.componentOne.firstchange` - this would mean that this is the first change sent by the components